# C++: Creating a function object with mem_fn and bind1st

Tags: c++, qt, concurrency, functional-programming, mem-fun

**Disclaimer**: This description contains a lot of Qt specific functionality. This is not necessary to answer the question, I'm just including it to explain the background.

I need to do some heavy computations in my QT application.
In order to do this, I would like to use `QtConcurrent::run(myFunction)` This is Qt's version of async and creates a future, which at some point will contain the result of `myFunction`.

The problem is that the function is both a member function and takes complex parameters.

I know that you can pass both a function and a pointer to QtConcurrent::run. The function will then be invoked on the pointer. You can even provide a list of parameters. But it seems like this list only accepts parameters such as `int`, `double` or `QString`.

**Actual Question:**

I would like to convert this line of code:

```
model->nextStep(simulatedResult->last().molecules, dt)
```

into

```
myFunction()
```

That means I need to

1. bind the pointer to the function
2. bind the arguments to the function

This is my code so far:

```
auto memfun=std::mem_fn(&ConcreteModel::nextStep);
auto memfun_bound_to_model=std::bind1st(memfun,model);
auto memfun_bound_result=std::bind1st(memfun_bound_to_model,simulatedResult->last().molecules);
auto memfun_bound_dt=std::bind1st(memfun_bound_result,dt);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.
There are 18 compiler errors, here is the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/2rBQgFNL

It would be great, if you could explain how to do this properly.
Not necessary for an answer, but even better, would be code for QtConcurrent::run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use a [**lambda expression.**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

```
auto myFunction = [&] { return model->nextStep(simulatedResult->last().molecules, dt); }
```

You could also use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) (see [@JonathanWakely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32634252/873025)'s answer), but lamda expressions are imho more universal and powerful.

Also, keep in mind that reading and writing to the same memory from multiple threads will result in a data race (don't pass pointers/references to mutable data to the QT threads unless synchronization is used).

Comment: Thanks for the warning regarding data races. But this is intentional. The result is very big, copies would waste a lot of memory. All access is synchronized ( at least I hope so)

Comment: @lhk Seems reasonable to not copy the data then. Glad to help!

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to mix the C++98 `bind1st` with the C++11 `mem_fn`, which isn't possible.

`bind1st` requires an [adaptable binary function](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/AdaptableBinaryFunction.html) which means one that defines certain typedefs, and one that takes *exactly* two arguments. You can't use it with something that requires more than two and keep binding one argument at a time.

In C++11 it is possible to wrap function objects without those typedefs, thanks to `decltype` and other new features, so "adaptable binary function" is a useless concept now, and `bind1st` is useless and deprecated.

The solution is simply to use C++11 features instead of `bind1st`, e.g. `std::bind` or a lambda expression.

```
auto myFunction = std::bind( &ConcreteModel::nextStep, model, simulatedResult->last().molecules, dt);
```